# requires ‘template<>’ syntax --> Call Class Template via a function

Tags: c++

I have a header class that looks like this:

```
#ifndef A_H__
#define A_H__

using namespace pcl::tracking;

namespace ball_tracking_cloud
{

template <typename PointType>
class OpenNISegmentTracking
{
public:
  //...

protected:
   void update(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &input_cloud);

  }; // end of class

} // end namespace

#endif
```

And now I have a .cpp file that looks like this:

```
#include <ball_tracking_cloud/particle_detector.h>

bool init = true;


namespace ball_tracking_cloud
{
void OpenNISegmentTracking<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::update(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &input_cloud)
{
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*input_cloud, *cloud);

    if(init)
    {
        v.run ();
        init=false;
    }

   v.cloud_cb(cloud);
}

} // end of namespace
```

If I compile my code I get this error:

```
: error: specializing member ‘ball_tracking_cloud::OpenNISegmentTracking<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::update’ requires ‘template<>’ syntax
 void OpenNISegmentTracking<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::update(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &input_cloud)
      ^
/hri/localdisk/markus/ros-alex/src/ball_tracking/ball_tracking_cloud/src/particle_detector.cpp:38:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
 } // end of namespace
 ^
```

I am not sure why I get this error..... I guess it has something to do with the fact that I use a template class ..... but I am not sure about this....

Any help would be great!

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what your problem is: you must declare the specialization using `template <>`. What's so unclear about that?

Comment: OT: Identifiers like `A_H__` are implementation reserved and must not be used.

Comment: @sqp_125 C++ can't be learned by guessing. A good [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is in order.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri But it is. If that link says otherwise, it is wrong.

Comment: @Ville-Valtteri It's 5.10/3 [lex.name] in N5659.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OpenNISegmentTracking` is what in `c++` terms is called a [full template specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization).

In other words, it's a version of your template that will be invoked, only when the template parameter is a `pcl::PointXYZRGBA`.

The proper syntax for such a definition is

```
template <>
void OpenNISegmentTracking<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::update(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &input_cloud)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this syntax for the function name:

```
template<>
void OpenNISegmentTracking<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::update(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr &input_cloud)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks adding this in the cpp file helped :)